# Add user to telegram channel after being banned - without having number memorised in contacts

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm working on the software to control the users within a Telegram channel. I need to add or ban users, which is quite easy using the following methods:

```
client(InviteToChannelRequest( channel, [user_to_add] )) # to add
client.edit_permissions(channel, user_to_ban, view_messages=False) # to ban
```

but I also need to add a user after it was previously banned. Apparently, this is not feasible because when someone is banned, in order to un-ban him ... both users (who invites and who is invited) must have - each other number - memorized. Otherwise, it doesn't work. So adding a new user the first time works, but as soon as it is banned, re-adding it is not possible unless both phones memorize each other number

Since I need to kick people in and out quite frequently and I cannot have numbers stored (simply because they might be many and don't know them to a level where I can ask to store my number), has anybody an idea about how this could be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://telegram.org/blog/autodelete-inv2#expiring-invite-links) new feature you may try to dig into one-time invite links creation using `ExportChatInviteRequest` and distribution. Frankly speaking this is the only way besides phone numbers exchange.